# Get other ldap query strings associated with a domain

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have in Softerra LDAP Administration something like the following:

> server: blah.gov
> OU=Domain Controllers etc...
> ldap://*subdomain*.blah.gov

I can't figure out how to, in C#, get those other ldap subdomain query strings.

I'm not sure how else to explain it, so ask questions and I'll try to clarify.

Updated: This is what Softerra LDAP Administrator looks like. The ldap queries near the bottom are not children of the above node, but somehow, the program knows about them and linked them in the GUI. If I could figure out how, that would fix my problem.

[image: Image and video hosting by TinyPic]

Comment: You mentioned C#.  Which class in C# are you trying to use?  What are you trying to do?  You mentioned subdomain query string.  Are you trying to write a LDAP query string?  Or are you trying to specify a bath path for the LDAP query?

Comment: Classes in the System.DirectoryServices namespace, including DirectorySearcher, among others. I am trying to write either many LDAP strings programmatically using a recursive method to follow the tree down or one single LDAP query that will search the subdomain Active Directory servers as well. Also, "bath path"?

Comment: Sorry, typo - I meant "base path"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Global Catalog to do the global search on your whole forest.  If you bind your DirectorySearcher to your global catalog, it should give you all the objects including your child domains.

If your forest doesn't have any global catalog or you don't have permission to bind to a global catalog (very rare), you have to enumerate all the domains in your forest and do the LDAP query one by one and aggregate the results on your own.

Here is a sample function that I draft for your reference.

```
IEnumerable<SearchResult> Search(string domain, string filter)
{
    DirectoryContext context = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Forest, domain);
    Forest forest = Forest.GetForest(context);
    GlobalCatalog gc = null;
    try
    {
        gc = forest.FindGlobalCatalog();
    }
    catch (ActiveDirectoryObjectNotFoundException)
    {
        // No GC found in this forest
    }

    if (gc != null)
    {
        DirectorySearcher searcher = gc.GetDirectorySearcher();
        searcher.Filter = filter;
        foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            yield return result;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (Domain d in forest.Domains)
        {
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(d.GetDirectoryEntry(), filter);
            foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll())
                yield return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like it, but this forest is EXTREMELY complicated, with more than 500 thousand users. This is an answer to my problem, but due to time constraints, we're going to have to go a different route. Thanks.

Comment: @seekerOfKnowledge I am interested in understanding your complicated environment and resolution, if possible :)

Comment: I can't actually. Sorry. Oh, and as far as the resolution goes, we have an ADAM instance that is much more neatly put together than the actual Active Directory, so we've just been querying from ADAM, but they messed up when setting up ADAM for proxy addresses, and they can't be gathered from ADAM, but we can get them from Active Directory. We also don't have the privilege of looking at how they get the records from Active Directory and put them in ADAM. I'm writing an application to match Payroll records to AD users, and we're already at 92%, so we're just going to wait for them to fix ADAM.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my BeaverTail LDAP browser - it's freeware, in 100% C# code, and available right here:

http://adsi.mvps.org/adsi/CSharp/beavertail.html

[image]

One of the most interesting LDAP addresses to go to is `LDAP://RootDSE` - it will show you a plethora of information on your AD forest and other interesting stuff. If you click on the root tree node in my Beavertail browser, you'll see the contents of that interesting system node.

Beavertail will also show you the AD hierarchy and show you what LDAP paths make up that hierachy.

Does that help at all??

Comment: Gives me a new tool to play with, but not really. Thanks though.